# Is there a .NET based programmer's text editor?

Tags: text-editors, .net-framework

I'm looking for a text editor that is powerful and extensible like emacs, but which uses .NET for the scripting language.  emacs is an astonishing and amazing thing, but I use .NET all day and so I'd like an editor that I could extend using the language that's in my head, instead of LISP, which is also astonishing and amazing, but not my main skill set.

Comment: Just an FYI, the ".NET Framework" is the set of software libraries & the framework written *in* C# that you use to write applications in C# with.  It's the equivalent of the STL to C++, you don't say you're using the STL to write your program/script, but rather, you're using C++.  That being said, off-hand, I'm not aware of any C#-based text editors - see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_text_editors for a list of some.

Comment: @Breakthrough [There are a few others as well](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_CLI_languages).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe not as powerful as Emacs, but [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) seems to support C# plugins. [This package](http://heanet.dl.sourceforge.net/project/sourcecookifier/other%20plugins/NppPlugin.NET.v0.5.zip) contains VS solutions for a template and a sample plugin. The [plugins wiki](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/notepad-plus/index.php?title=Plugin_Development#How_to_develop_a_plugin) might also come in handy.

Comment: Giving Notepad++ a shot now.  It looks promising.